# Set radio button checked when click on textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, textarea

Trying to set radio button checked when click on textarea.
There is a label for radio button and inside the label there is a textarea so what i need is that when clicking on the textarea to write the input will be checked.

```
<input type="radio" name="msg_form" id="invite0" value="0" <? if ($msg_form == 0) { echo 'checked'; } ?>>

<label for="invite0">

    <textarea class="selfmessage" for="invite0" oninput="replaceName(this)" style="height: auto !important;" name="self_invite" type="text" placeholder="write something..."></textarea>

</label>
```

Comment: place radio input inside label

Comment: @NirajKaushal that doesn't work here as the `textarea` itself is a clickable element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `keyup` or `input` or `change` or `focus` or whatever you like as a trigger. [here is a list of often used trigger](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_events.asp)

```js
$('.selfmessage').on('focus', function(e) {
  $('#invite0').prop('checked', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="msg_form" id="invite0" value="0"><label for="invite0">
<textarea class="selfmessage" for="invite0" style="height: auto !important;" name="self_invite" type="text" placeholder="write something..."></textarea>
</label>
```

Comment: Your description states different events that your code is using.

Comment: I've changed it ;) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using `parent()` to get the `label` wrapping the `textarea`, then `prev()` to get the input and `prop()` to set it to `checked`:

```js
$('.selfmessage').on({
  'focus': function() {
    $(this).parent().prev(':radio').prop('checked', true);
  },
  'input': replaceName
});

function replaceName() {
  // your logic here...
}
```

```css
.selfmessage {
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" name="msg_form" id="invite0" value="0">
<label>
  <textarea class="selfmessage" name="self_invite" type="text" placeholder="write something..."></textarea>
</label>
```

Note that the functionality of the `label` here is pretty much entirely redundant given your example code. I only left it in in case your UI styling depends on it. If it doesn't I'd suggest removing it.

Also note that I removed the `oninput` event attribute and changed it to an unobtrusive handler, and also changed the inline styling to external CSS. Inline JS and CSS should always be avoided where possible.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.selfmessage').on('keyup', function(e) {
if($('.selfmessage').val().length>0){
 $('#invite0').prop('checked', true);
}else{
 $('#invite0').prop('checked', false);
}
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="msg_form" id="invite0" value="0"><label for="invite0">
<textarea class="selfmessage" for="invite0" style="height: auto !important;" name="self_invite" type="text" placeholder="write something..."></textarea>
</label>
```

Add a `keyup` event to `textarea` then check the `textarea` empty or not. if not empty enable `checkbox` else diable it.

Comment: Please take the time to describe what the issues are and why this solution helps. Remember, we're here to educate people, not just dump code on them.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#id-textarea').click(function(){
    $("#id-checkbox").attr("checked", true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<input type="checkbox" id="id-checkbox"/>
<textarea id="id-textarea"></textarea>
</html>
```